Example of principal $G$-bundle $E\xrightarrow{p}B$ with classes in the kernel of $p^{*}$ that are not characteristic classes
If $E\xrightarrow{p}B$ is a principal $G$-bundle classified by $B\xrightarrow{f}BG$, then the image of any characteristic class of $B$ under $p^*$ is trivial by the naturality of $H^*$ and the fact that $EG$ is weakly contractible.
I am doubtful that the kernel of $p^*$ consists only of characteristic classes, but am struggling to find a concrete counterexample.
